# С#: передача параметров с POST запросом

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, клиент-сервер

Столкнулся с интересно задачей - требуется на сервер послать параметры и в ответ получить XML.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(is_card_URL);
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(params_);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream2);

string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
stream2.Close();
```

Сам код работает, но нужно вместе с УРЛ также послать параметры (допустим, **а,b,c**) Я пробовал дописывать в УРЛ (...?a=1&b=2&c=3), но сервер не видит параметров, в ответе он пишет, что параметры не переданы.

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как в данном случае можно передать параметры на сервер?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметры для POST запроса передаются немного по-другому:

```
string postParameters = "a=1&b=2&c=3";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(is_card_URL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = postParameters.Length;
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    requestWriter.Write(postParameters);
}
```

Если передаваемая строка может содержать недопустимые символы, ее предварительно нужно закодировать:

```
string parameters = ...;
string postParameters = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameters);
```

Дополнительно можно указать желаемую кодировку:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
```

В общем случае, когда нужно передать произвольные данные, используется байтовый массив:

```
byte[] postData = ...;
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
}
```

Тогда пример с передачей строки можно свести к следующему коду:

```
string parameters = ...;
byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameters));
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
}
```

Comment: есть ли отличие в реализации: для http и https ?

Comment: @LeonardBertone если не нужны дополнительные заморочки с креденшиалами/сертификатами, то нет.

Answer (score 3):

Если нет принципиальной необходимости работать именно через `WebRequest`/`WebResponse`, то самый простой способ - использование [`System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] response =
    client.UploadValues(is_card_URL, new NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "a", "1" },
        { "a", "2" },
        { "c", "3" }
    });

    string result = UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В отличие от GET-запроса POST получает параметры в теле, а не в строке запроса, а размер передаваемых данных указывается в заголовке ContentLength.

Сделайте например так:

```
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString);
        webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
```

Плюс небольшая ремарка: никогда не используйте просто Close/Dispose без using или try для потоков, запросов и прочих освобождаемых ресурсов. Это источник потенциальных проблем

Comment: Вроде бы `stream.Close` не нужен?

Comment: queryString в данном случае включает только параметры или всю адресную строку ?

Comment: только параметры

Comment: это здесь параметры ассоцицируются с запросом: webRequest.GetRequestStream()?

Comment: @LeonardBertone эмм....что?

Comment: каким образом вашем примере параметры передаются на сервер? я так понял они выливаются в отдельный поток, а потом что дальше с ними происходит и как они попадают на сервер?

Comment: @LeonardBertone если посмотрите повнимательнее, то увидите, что это не просто какой-то там отдельный поток. Это поток самого запроса, соответственно, данные пишутся именно в запрос. А уже запрос передается серверу

Comment: спасибо за ответ. а скажите, параметры так передаются: "param1=a&param2=b" ?и если в имени параметра есть символ "$", его нужно кодировать?