# Отправка параметров JSON на веб-сервис из C#

Tags: c#, веб-служба

Мне нужно из C# отправить сделать то, что делается через CURL таким образом:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: 
application/json' --header 'x-mobilephone: +79251111111' -d '{
  "parameters": [
    {

    }
  ],
  "operType": "Universal"
}' 'http://dc1-test1:8091/sendSms'
```

Я никак не пойму как это сделать. Простите, не очень сведущ в веб-технологиях. я правильно понимаю,что 'x-mobilephone: +79251111111' это параметр запроса, т.е. если смотреть в [С#: передача параметров с POST запросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418214/%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC) , то это нужно передать в params_ в виде "x-mobilephone=+79251111111"; А куда класть следующее?

```
'{
     "parameters": [
        {

        }
       ],
      "operType": "Universal"
 }'
```

Comment: У вас жеж написано `--header 'x-mobilephone: +79251111111'` - то есть это не параметр, а заголовок. А вот json, что вы показали - как раз параметр.

Answer (score 1):

Все четко написано:

URL: `http://dc1-test1:8091/sendSms`

Headers:

- `Content-Type: application/json`
- `Accept: application/json`
- `x-mobilephone: +79251111111`

Body:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {

    }
  ],
  "operType": "Universal"
}
```

Говоря об отправке запроса я бы советовал использовать асинхронные методы класса [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) вместо `WebRequest`.